# How to create a drop down button without showing the selected value

Tags: flutter

I am trying to create a page with `DropdownButton` widget component in it. This is my code:

```
Padding(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
    right: 16.0,
  ),
  child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
    child: DropdownButton<String>(
      icon: Icon(
        Icons.more_vert,
      ),
      iconSize: 24,
      elevation: 16,
      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.deepPurple),
      items: <String>['Edit', 'Delete']
          .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
        return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
          value: value,
          child: Text(value),
        );
      }).toList(),
      onChanged: (newValue) {},
    ),
  ),
),
```

Everything looks good and well.

[image]

However, the code above creates a unnecessary space on the left as you can see here:

[image]

I need to remove this unnecessary space on the left. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried founding the best possible answer for you and certainly found out that [PopupMenuButton flutter](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/PopupMenuButton-class.html) is the one for you.

You can use it in your code like this, and you are pretty much good to go.

```
           Container(
             color: Colors.indigo, // this is for your reference, can be removed
             // here is your padding
             padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 0.0, right: 16.0), 
             child: PopupMenuButton<String>(
                itemBuilder: (context) {
                  return <String>["Edit", "Delete"].map((str) {
                    return PopupMenuItem(
                      value: str,
                      child: Text(str),
                    );
                  }).toList();
                },
                child: Icon(Icons.more_vert, color: Colors.white),
                onSelected: (value) {}
              )
           )
```

**Result**

[image: Result Image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the space , I'd recommend you to use a popmenu widget:

```
    PopupMenuButton(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 0.0, right: 16.0), 
        elevation: 3.2,
        initialValue: choices[1],
        onCanceled: () {
          print('You have not chossed anything');
        },
        tooltip: 'This is tooltip',
        onSelected: _select,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) {
          return choices.map((CustomPopupMenu choice) {
            return PopupMenuItem(
              value: choice,
              child: Text(choice.title),
            );
          }).toList();
        },
      )
```